# How do I release my media player after it is done playing?

Tags: java, android, release, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a sound board and after clicking about 30 different sounds it stops working; I believe android is running out of memory. Below is my code. How can I implement .release() so that when the sound is done playing it is released? I don't really care if two things play at the same time; the clips are t0o short for this to be possible. I would just like to get my code set.

```
public class soundPageOne extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.soundsone);

        final MediaPlayer pg1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.peter1);
        Button playSound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.peter1Button);

        playSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pg1.start();

        }
    });
```

I have done a lot of searching around but due to my lack of java/android knowledge I have not been able to get anything to work. Thanks in advance, let me know if anyone needs anymore code.

Comment: Try this method **onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)** is helpful when audio is complete

Comment: Yes, I am currently trying that. When I use that with mp.release() and try to replay the button, the class crashes. have any idea? @Sanket990

Comment: actually mp.release() means you are releasing mediaplayer object. you can not start again(mp.play()) calling play.

Comment: you can apply oncompletion -onstop() method after you are object again mp.prepare() and mp.start()

Comment: set all below thing in onCompletion() add below methods
**mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();**

Comment: How am I going to setDataSource if I have multiple buttons? won't I only be able to define one path? @sanket990

Comment: There is a limit to the number of `MediaPlayer` objects that can have resources allocated at any given time. I would recommend following Allan's advice and use `SoundPool` for what you require, but if you insist on using `MediaPlayer` it can be done. How many concurrent sounds would you like to be able to play at once?

Comment: I have heard bad things about sound pool for soundboards. I dont care how many are playing at once, what ever makes it not stop working @Dave

Comment: I just posted an answer with what I had in mind. You can increase the length of the array for more concurrent sounds, but what's there should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left a comment, but I'll post an answer to show what I mean anyway...

The idea is that you have a set number of `MediaPlayer` instances that you can use. That way you never exceed the maximum number of instances. The array should be the length of the number of concurrent sounds you expect to be able to hear. If the sounds are local files, the length of time it takes to prepare the sounds should be almost negligible, so calling `create` inside the click handler should not result in terrible performance. Each of your buttons is associated with a particular resource, I suppose, so I set up a helper method to create and play the sounds for each button in the same way.

```
public class soundPageOne extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer[] mPlayers = new MediaPlayer[2];
    private int mNextPlayer = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.soundsone);
        Button playSound1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.peter1Button);
        playSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSound(R.raw.peter1);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy(); // <---------------------- This needed to be there
        for (int i = 0; i < mPlayers.length; ++i)
            if (mPlayers[i] != null)
                try {
                    mPlayers[i].release();
                    mPlayers[i] = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    // handle...
                }
    }

    private void startSound(int id) {
        try {
            if (mPlayers[mNextPlayer] != null) {
                mPlayers[mNextPlayer].release();
                mPlayers[mNextPlayer] = null;
            }
            mPlayers[mNextPlayer] = MediaPlayer.create(this, id);
            mPlayers[mNextPlayer].start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle
        }
        finally {
            ++mNextPlayer;
            mNextPlayer %= mPlayers.length;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is it necessary to have the onDestory() method? it seems when ever i hit the back button to go back to the menu the app crashes and its got something to do with the ondestroy ("did not call through to super.ondestroy")

Comment: Fixed it. And yes, you should have that.

Comment: what exactly is it doing? I was able to get the app to run fine with out it and had no problems. I know that it is doing something when the current page is destroyed, but I don't see why its important

Comment: It's just cleaning up allocated resources when the app is destroyed. Those resources live with the MediaPlayerService, and so should not be leaked exactly, but it's good practice to deallocate things yourself when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class, say `AudioPlayer` with a `SoundPool` variable.  Setup a constructor to initialise the `AudioPlayer` object and create a `Play` method.  SoundPool works better for short sounds played many times and does not require you to release.

```
public class AudioPlayer {

    private SoundPool sPool = new SoundPool(Integer.MAX_VALUE, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    public AudioPlayer(Context c, int id){  
        sounds.put("1",sPool.load(c, id, 1));   
    }

    public void play(Context c) {
        sPool.play("1", 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}
```

So your class should look like

```
public class soundPageOne extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundsone);

    final AudioPlayer ap = new AudioPlayer(this, R.raw.sound);
    Button playSound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.peter1Button);

    playSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ap.play();

    }
});
```

Comment: So am I setting up two separate java files for each one of these?

Comment: Also, this doesn't really answer my question. I am not trying to be a prick, this is just out of my knowledge and I don't know how to set any of it up, which is why I just asked for a way to release my current media player as I already have 180 buttons programmed with mediaplayer. I might give your code a try in a little bit if I can't find the answer to my original question. Thanks though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah 2 java files. Your original one and a new AudioPlayer file.  This is a much cleaner and more effective way of playing sounds and I would recommend using it.  However, I posted another answer that is more along the lines of what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)?

Something like:

```
public class soundPageOne extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.soundsone);
        final MediaPlayer pg1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.peter1);

        //***set the listener here***
        pg1.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        Button playSound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.peter1Button);

        playSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pg1.start();
            }   
        });
    }

    //***this code will be executed once the sound finishes playing***
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //log messages, other things can go here
        mp.release();
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure; I am very inexperienced. Where would I try to put this in my code? And what are the "..." for?

Comment: ... is for whatever other code you want to do when the media player finishes (a log message, maybe?). I'll edit my answer to flesh out the code a bit...

Comment: I thought that's what it was for. I really don't want to do anything else (at least I don't think I do). I am just tired of overloading my app with media players and I need a way to end them. But yeah I just don't know where to place this in my code or what to change in it or if it is necessary to repeat for all buttons. Sorry for the ignorance, thanks for all the help @psyren89

Comment: Okay so this works, but once I try to play the button again it crashes  soundPageOne class. I tried to put reset after release but that doesn't work. Any ideas? @psyren89

Comment: Move your media player creation code (final MediaPlayer pg1... and pg1.setOnCompletion...) into the onClick() method.

Comment: I get errors from moving both (or just one) of them. Damn. @psyren89

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Your activity class:

```
public class soundPageOne extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundsone);

    final AudioPlayer pg1 = new AudioPlayer();
    Button playSound1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.peter1Button);

    playSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pg1.play(this, R.raw.sound);

    }
});
```

}

This is another Java Class:

```
public class AudioPlayer {

private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

public void stop() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void play(Context c, int sound) {

    stop();

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, sound);

    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            stop();
        }
    });

    mPlayer.start();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mPlayer != null;
}
```

}

Comment: Your other answer is much better. This one looks like it will always crash as it is. `pg1` is set to `null`, then you call `start`. Missing some intermediate code perhaps?